# Computed Fields in Sitecore 7.2 odd behavior

Tags: lucene, sitecore, computed-field

I have build a couple of computed fields and its been working fine, but after I refactored my code and structure, the different computed fields exhibit odd behaviour.

One works and lets my halt the code at a breakpoint, the other does not.

The code looks identical, the index config is the same, no change other than I changed the values for the assembly and namespace after the refactoring.

```
<fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="DateStart" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="DateEnd" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="Appetizer" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="Title" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="ApplicationDeadline" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="Location" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="Engagement" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <field fieldName="computedCountries" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <Analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="computedMarkets" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <Analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>

          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="computedMarkets">Ram.SC.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MarketComputedField, Ram.SC.ContentSearch</field>
            <field fieldName="computedCountries">Ram.SC.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CountryComputedField, Ram.SC.ContentSearch</field>
          </fields>
```

So I cant figure out where the bone is buried.

I hope you can help me out :)

/Robin

Comment: Check the  /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to make sure the index configuration looks as expected. Also have you tried rebuilding your solution? maybe some catching is behind this

Comment: Typos is the class/assembly names? This is a patch file so maybe do a /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to make sure that the settings are not being overidden by other patch files.

Comment: I just saw that its failing because the MoreLinq class library apparently isn't referenced correctly in the project, but this adds to the confusion, because then why does the other one work ???, this was logged in the Crawling log file.

Comment: Typos were the first thing I was checking. I also reloaded the solution cleaning cache files such as the compile cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

In the end it was an inconsistency between framework versions, which I only found out by looking in the crawling.log file.

/Robin